# How to use mdfind for a literal exact match in filename?

Tags: macos, mdfind

I want to locate a literal filename exact match, and not all files containing that word in their name.
I tried `mdfind -name "^filename$"` but the regexp doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a `-literal` option:

```
mdfind -literal "kMDItemDisplayName == filename"
```

I don't know if this can be shortened, but it seems to work for me.

Comment: Hard to remember kMDItemDisplayName param !